# Add record="RECORD_FROM_RINGING" attribute to TwilioML XML using Java in ColdFusion

Tags: java, xml, coldfusion, twilio

We are using ColdFusion and Java to generate the Twilio Markup / XML necessary for handling Twilio calls in our webhook.

Currently, everything works well. The output xml/twiml generated looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Response>
        <Dial callerId="+18184461999">
            <Number>+18554904999</Number>
        </Dial>
    </Response>
```

We generated this markup using java classes in ColdFusion, mainly because ColdFusion can't do it natively. This is the ColdFusion/Java code we currently use to generate the above xml:

```
<cfscript>
    TWILIO_CALLER_ID = "+18184461999";
    tophn="+18554904999";

    objPattern = CreateObject("java","java.util.regex.Pattern").Compile(JavaCast( "string", "^[\\d\\+\\-\\(\\) ]+$"));
    objMatcher=objPattern.Matcher(JavaCast( "string", tophn ));
    dialBuilder = createObject("java","com.twilio.twiml.Dial$Builder").init();
    dialBuilder.callerId(TWILIO_CALLER_ID);
    numberbuilder= createObject("java","com.twilio.twiml.Number$Builder").init(tophn).build();
    dialBuilder = dialBuilder.number(numberbuilder);
    voiceTwimlResponse = createObject("java","com.twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse$Builder").dial(dialBuilder.build()).build();

    response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' & voiceTwimlResponse.toXml();
</cfscript>
```

Everything above works perfectly for our needs.

However, now we would like to add an attribute to the "Dial" element: `record="RECORD_FROM_RINGING"`. Below is what the XML we would like generated would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Response>
        <Dial callerId="+18184461999" record="RECORD_FROM_RINGING">
            <Number>+18554904999</Number>
        </Dial>
    </Response>
```

How would we use ColdFusion + java to accomplish this? We have spent hours trying to figure this out, and nothing works for us. We have looked into the Record and Record$Builder classes, but found nothing that adds this attribute the way we need it. The closest we got to was being able to add a `<Record />` element before the `<Dial>` element, but that does not work for us.

How do we add the attribute `record="RECORD_FROM_RINGING"` to the `<Dial>` element using ColdFusion and the appropriate Java classes/objects? All we require is the attribute to be set for that element.

Comment: I believe this worked with version 5 of the API.

var dial = createObject("java","com.twilio.sdk.verbs.Dial").init(arguments.number);
dial.setRecord("record-from-rigning")

Comment: BTW there a Twilio wrapper for ColdFusion: https://github.com/jasonfill/ColdFusion-Twilio-Library

Comment: @James A Mohler: Outdated and no longer works. First thing we tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you are using an older version of the jar which does not support all of the [`<Dial>` attributes](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial). Looks like the [Twilio instructions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/devenvironment) link to an older version (currently 7.0.0). The [GitHub version](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java) is already up to 7.8.0. Try [downloading 7.8.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twilio.sdk/twilio/7.8.0) or building a newer version from the source (do not forget the dependencies).

The [Dial.Builder](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/twilio/twiml/Dial.java) class in 7.8.0 contains a new method named `options(String key, String value)` which supports arbitrary attributes. Use it to set the "record" attribute like this:

```
...
recordOption = createObject("java","com.twilio.twiml.Dial$Record");
dialBuilder.options("record", recordOption.RECORD_FROM_RINGING.toString());
...
```

<sub>** Using the `Dial.Record` enum, instead of a hard coded string, helps insulate the code against changes in the API.</sub>

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
   <Dial callerId="+18185551999" record="record-from-ringing">
      <Number>+18185554999</Number>
   </Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. I have implemented this solution and it worked perfectly. I installed the latest JAR (7.8.0) that you linked to, then added the code, and it worked by adding the appropriate attribute and recorded the call as required. Thanks a million!

Comment: Glad I could help :) To avoid possible version conflicts down the road, I kept both jars, but removed the `com.twilio` package from the old one using 7zip. So it only contains the dependencies. Renamed for clarity: `twilio-7.8.0.jar` (twilio classes only) and `twilio-7.0.0-rc-dependencies-only.jar`

Comment: (Yes, I know you can use `this.javaSettings` but CF already includes some of those libs causing a version conflict in CF11. I was too lazy to figure out exactly which libs caused it and only load the others ;-)